# Fixed positioning in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Windows Store-style WPF application, and I just added search to it.  When I click the Search button in the app bar, I set my `FlyoutPresenter` containing the `SearchBox` to `Visible`.  This button is placed in the lower right-hand corner.  It works good on computers with keyboards, but I ran into a problem when the virtual keyboard, or `InputPane`, opens.  First, the keyboard covered the box.  I solved that problem by checking and adjusting the margin of the box when the box is in focus, but when I scroll the page to the very top and bottom, the control starts moving on the page.  Here is my minimal code:

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid">

    <!-- App Bar with Search button -->
    <AppBar x:Name="BAppBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="Search" Click="Search_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </AppBar>

    <!-- Search button and Close button -->
    <FlyoutPresenter VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="SearchPop" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SearchBox Name="Search" GotFocus="Search_Focus" LostFocus="Search_Focus"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="SearchClose" Icon="Cancel" Click="Search_Close" />
        </StackPanel>
    </FlyoutPresenter>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Close app bar, show search box, and set margin to bottom of page
    private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BAppBar.IsOpen = false;
        SearchPop.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

        SearchPop.Margin = new Thickness(0, MainGrid.ActualHeight - SearchPop.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
    }

    // Set margin for opening/closing virtual keyboard
    private void Search_Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
        {
            double flyoutOffset = (int)args.OccludedRect.Height - SearchPop.ActualHeight;
            SearchPop.Margin = new Thickness(0, flyoutOffset, 0, 0);
        };
        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += (s, args) =>
        {
            SearchPop.Margin = new Thickness(0, MainGrid.ActualHeight - SearchPop.ActualHeight, 0, 0);
        };
    }

    // Close search
    private void Search_Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchPop.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

What I need is for the box to not be affected by the user scrolling in the screen.  In HTML, this is called Fixed Positioning.  I have read that it is not natively possible in XAML, but that there are workarounds.  I have read these MSDN and SO links, but they didn't really help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9779328a-a7cd-447d-a4ac-bcc952083f43/fixed-positioning-in-wpf?forum=wpf

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7349d01d-dc0e-4e1c-9327-df90e00fbebf/how-to-handle-the-appearance-of-the-onscreen-keyboard?forum=winappswithcsharp

[Popup control moves with parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736359/popup-control-moves-with-parent)

Comment: OK, just to let everybody know, I never solved this question as it is, but I fixed my problem by moving the search box to the top of the page while the InputPane is open.  Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate the fixed behavior in XAML in a very simple way:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid">
    <ContentControl VerticalAligment="Stretch" HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
    <!--All other visual controls, the float item will be located over all controls    located here, even scrolls viewers-->
    </ContentControl>

    <!-- Float item -->
    <SomeControl>
    <!--The control you want be over in the fixed position, 
        you can set the layout to it, and locate it where you want
        just set the Vertical/Horizontal Aligment, margin, height, width-->
    </SomeControl>
</Grid>
```

(Sorry if code sample has some sintax errors, I had write it in the fly)
Also wpf has some controls that are displayed on a layer over all other, this elements are context menus, tooltips and adorners, you also could try them.

I hope this ideas helps.

Comment: I will most certainly look into this.  I do know about tooltips, but they disappear when the mouse is taken away, while this needs to stay open until the user closes it.  I did not know about adorners until after I wrote about this question, but I have already looked into them, and they are not supported on Windows Store apps (yet).  I haven't looked into tooltips yet, but will do so.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  What is happening, is when the InputPane opens, the entire grid is shifted up.  It doesn't work like this in any other app on my system, so there has to be a way to make the InputPane just slide over the grid, not push it up.  Right now, that is what I am looking into.  Everything else will be easy then.